# Expected declaration while accessing global variable from second view controller

Tags: swift

I just try to access from second VC a globally declared variable which I've created in first VC. I received in the second VC the error:

"Expected declaration"

on all variables in second VC. (switched1, switched2, switched3)
What is wrong here:

**First ViewController:**

```
import UIKit

var switched1:Bool = false
var switched2:Bool = false
var switched3:Bool = false

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    ...
    switched1 = true
    switched2 = true
    switched3 = false
    ...

}
```

**Second Viewcontroller:**

```
import UIKit

class VC_second: UIViewController {

    ...
    if switched1 == true {
      println("TEST1")
    }

    if switched2 == true {
      println("TEST2")
    }

    if switched3 == true {
      println("TEST3")
    }
    ...

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot execute code in the declaration part of a class. The code needs to be in a function body:

```
class VC_second: UIViewController {

    func someFunction() {
        if switched1 == true {
          println("TEST1")
        }

        if switched2 == true {
            println("TEST2")
        }

        if switched3 == true {
            println("TEST3")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should never compare a bool to true. It is redundant. If switched1 { ... }